# Prime counter program debug

Tags: python-3.x, primes

I'm trying to write a program that counts the number of primes in a given interval

I came up with this:

```
def check_primes(numb):
    if numb == 2 :
        return True
    n = 2
    while n < numb:
        if numb % n != 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False


def count_primes(num) :
    count = 0
    for m in range(2,num) :
        if check_primes(m) == True :
            count += 1

    return count
```

but when I try count_primes(100) I get 50 instead of 25, for some reason. Can anyone explain to me what's wrong in there?

Answer (score 0):

In your `while`, you are not increasing `n`. Your method runs for just `n=2` and that's it.

So, just add `n += 1` to your `while`:

```py
def check_primes(numb):
    if numb == 2 :
        return True
    n = 2
    while n < (numb // 2) + 1:
        if numb % n != 0:
            n += 1
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

Also note that there is not need to check all numbers to `numb`. You can do check it till `numb/2` and that would be enough.

Comment: You can actually only check up to `n * n <= numb` - any number larger than the square root of `numb` would have to be multiplied by a factor smaller than `sqrt(numb)`, of which would already have been checked.

Comment: Thank you very much Amin! The second modification just makes the code more computationally efficient, but it's not strictly needed, is it?

Comment: No. It's optional and makes your code performance better.@jp